# Convert in UTC time format in c#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I need to set expire date of product as present date till midnight as shown below in UTC format.

"2021-05-28T23:59:59Z"

How i can write this in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString("o")
```

The output of above is

> 2021-05-28T23:59:59.0000000Z

Comment: did u mean like this
product.ExpirationDate=System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString("s");
should i concat Z?How should i add this?

Comment: Yes the above code gives the string representation of date what you require.

Comment: Then you can use `"o"` as format. I've updated the answer.